# SQL autoincrememnt and archiveing old data

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

i am building a web application and have an intermidiate understanding of mysql.

i'm trying to wrap my head around a problem i see.

my system may be in usage for 10 years. i'm concerned about running out of auto increment values.

will it be possible to archive or dump old data out of the system to open up old auto increment values that were used prior?

i have read that auto increment will continue until it reaches the max value for an int then throw errors.... ?

i'm looking for any information about this issue. example how other systems like accounting systems deal with this limitations.

i'm using my auto incrememnt

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't revert to old and obsolete autoinc values. Why not set the corresponding column as `BIGINT`? This way your app could possibly run decades without hitting a boundary.

I forgot tho tell you that you would have to take care of the new type within your application logic (I presume it's PHP). Do not use integers, use float instead.

Answer (score 1):

int unsigned = 430 million per year for 10 years

should be enough if not use bigint unsigned  :P

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your maximum auto increment value by changing your id column to something like a [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) - it supports numbers up to 9223372036854775807, you will never need more. And no, you can't free up old id values for new entries with that id.

Comment: unsigned it supports up to 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with int.  You could go with a GUID column or natural key but there's no reason to give up the query performance.  Joining on ints will be faster than joining guid columns or composite keys.  See the docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/numeric-types.html) for a definition of the type ranges.  UNSIGNED int or BIGINT are good bets to dispel your worries about running out of numbers...